# AppEngine entity modeling - minimizing entity groups and achieving atomic cascading update/delete

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

Am learning AppEngine and have started developing new app and want to clarify something.

I understood that 
a. To achieve atomicity of update/delete of several entities we need to do it in a transaction and hence all should fall under same entity group
b. Having big entity groups is not scalable as it causes contention.
(Q1: Correct?)

So here is an entity model of an online examination system for sake of discussion:

Entities:
Subject 
Exam
Page
Question
Answer

As you can see from top, each entity 1 - many relationship with the immediate bottom one i.e 1 Subject can have many exams, 1 exam -> many pages, 1 page can have many questions...

As you can see, i would like to establish cascading update/delete relationship among these entities (JPA datanucleus appengine implemention supports this (under the hood) by putting all entities under same entity group (Q2: Correct?) though AppEngine natively doesn't support this constraint) so naturally all would go under same entity group so that 
a. i can delete a Page (if my user does) in a transaction and be sure that all pages, questions, answers are all deleted
b. or i can delete a subject altogether in a transaction all clear all stuff underneath it

So when i extend this to my real app, i see that all of my (or atleast most) entities are interrelated and fit into same entity group to be able to transact them altogether - making my model inefficient.

Q3: Please advice on how to rethink this design (and the best practice) and still achieve what i need. Ask me more if needed. 
Would be great if you could point me to relevant examples.

p.s. 1 solution i could think of is having each entity in a separate entity group and a separate persistent field in each entity (say Exam) named 'IS_DELETED' defaulting to FALSE (value 0). Once a user deletes an Exam, i will set the field to 1 (TRUE) and that i don't load them anymore. I shall write a Cron job which clears all related entities in separate separate transaction in the backend which will retry upon failures if needed. But am sure this is not elegant and not sure whether this will work out..

Thanks all for your responses,
Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to improve things is to just have fewer entities in the first place.  I can't really think of a terribly good reason why pages, questions and answers need to be separate entities.   I suspect you normally display all of the questions on a single page in the same request, without exception.  If that's really the case, just keep them in one entity.

It does make a lot of sense to use the Exam entities as the parent for pages; for one thing, each exam is probably limited to a reasonable, small number of pages, so scaling this up probably won't hurt much.

On the other hand, there probably *are* a great many exams per subject, and for that reason, subjects should *not* appear in the ancestry of exams (and by extension, pages).

If, for some reason you needed to delete all of the exams in the subject of math, even if they were in the same entity group, you'd probably be unable to complete the whole delete in one transaction without timing out.  You might even have trouble completing the delete in a single request.

That suggests that you should be using the Task Queue for this operation.  When a cascading change on a subject occurs, the request handler needs to insert a new task and then just return successfully.  don't forget to just update the subject entity right there in the request handler.

The task queue pulls a block of affected entities from the datastore, updates them, and then checks the time.  If there is still more time available for continued updates, it pulls another block of entities, and so on, until none remain.  If time is almost up, the task just adds itself back to the queue so it can restart where it left off when it respawns.

It's a good idea to schedule the first task at least a few seconds into the future of the initial request, so that if, for instance, the subject was deleted, the delete can propagate to future requests and no new exams in that subject can be created by the time the task starts.

Comment: However i couldn't understand last paragraph still. May be i should first learn Task Queue? Mainly 'the delete can propagate to future requests and no new exams in that subject can be created by the time the task starts.' How does this ensure that no new exams can be added in subsequent requests? If i understood correctly, do you mean that task will first delete Subject (alone) (and then slowly all Exams) so that in future requests i can ensure that since Subject is NOT present, an Exam can't be added under it by checking (non) existence of Subject.

Comment: Also what if task queue fails to delete certain entities. May be we need to handle manually by retrying? Reason am asking is transaction doesn't leave us in inconsistent state. So just want to be sure that is simulated in your suggested way. Thanks again.

Comment: "first delete Subject (alone) (and then slowly all Exams" Correct!

Comment: If you have more than 1000 entities to delete, then it will certainly fail to delete some of them, just by fiat of the datastore.  The only way to deal with that is to retry on the remaining rows.   Updating the parent first means that all future updates to children are consistent, and only old children need the corrective action of the task.  scheduling the task in the future insures that all updates that the task needs to worry about have happened and propagated through the datastore, and are now not a subject of contention.

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy!,                                                 btw, guys, any other suggestions/comments?